# Why do I have to escape my already escaped search string in a for loop in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, findstr

After trawling through S.O. I've managed to piece together my function so it works, but I don't understand something about it. I'm basically trying to ensure that a file I want to use doesn't have double quotes in it. I've used findstr with the /m option which is returning the filename.

When I run the command from the cmd line it works with this:

```
findstr /V /L /m "\"" filename.txt
```

When filename has no double quotes it returns the filename, if it does have double quote it returns blank / null /whatever. Exactly what I want.

So I wanted to capture this result in a variable, using a solution on this website. I've discovered this works:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set test=
for /F %%a in ('findstr /V /L /m ^"^\^"^" filename.txt') do (@set test=!test! %%a)

echo %test%
```

So my question: My search string needs to be escaped so goes from:

```
"\""
```

and becomes:

```
^"^\^"^"
```

but I don't understand why I have to do that. Can anybody explain?

Comment: Technically, only the first quote need to be escaped, so you can just say `^"\""`

Comment: This worked fine for me: `for /F %%G in ('findstr /V /M ^""" *.txt') do echo %%G`

Comment: ahhhh right ok, just that first quote.. thanks.

that at least will make it easier to read.

Comment: I would probably do it like `findstr /V /L /M ^"\"" "filename.txt"`, because the file name appears quoted (best practice as some special characters might cause trouble otherwise), and the search string portion `^"\""` contains balanced quotes from `cmd`'s point of view (the first `"` is escaped by `^`, so it does not count; then there are two `""`); the core issue here is that `cmd` uses `^` for escaping while `findstr` uses `\ `instead; you have to keep in mind that `cmd` is parsing the entire command line *first*, and *afterwards*, `findstr` is interpreting its arguments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, the reason why your search string needs to be escaped (`^` escaped) is ... none. In your case you search string does not need to be escaped.

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
        findstr /l /m /v  "\"" *.txt
    ') do echo %%a
```

You need the `\"` escape because the `findstr` argument handling (more [here](http://www.daviddeley.com/autohotkey/parameters/parameters.htm#WIN)) but the `^"` scaping is not **required**.

But there are some cases where the `^` quote scaping is needed. The reason for the escaping in those cases is that the command inside the `for /f` is executed in a separate `cmd` instance. This started instance could (or not) include its own set of quotes

```
cmd /c " ...... "
```

and the quotes in your command could interfere in the `cmd` parsing of the command to execute.

But if you escape the quotes (`cmd` escaping, that is `^"`), they will not be parsed as closing/opening quotes, but as a literal without a special meaning for the `cmd` parser, so they could be hadled later.

Comment: well this is embarrassing :)  Im certain id tried that but obviously not!thank you for pointing it out.